# Keylemon Internal Server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, internal-server-error

I was trying to implement the Keylemon JS REST API as part of a website authentication system. The problem i am running into is that any request sent to the keylemon.php backend file gets a 500 internal server error as the response. I have configured my .htaccess file as given in the documentation on Keylemon website and also added an alias. This is the code i am using to do so.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /backend/keylemon.php [L,QSA]
Alias /backend /backend/keylemon.php
```

And this is my frontend file:

```
require(['keylemon'], function (keylemon) {
      keylemon.init({
          modality : "face",
          func : "create_identity",
          target : '#keylemon',
          backendUrl : "backend",
          bundlePath : "frontend",
          onIdentityCreated : function(identity_id, model_id){
              // biometric model and identity successfully created
                    alert('id created'+identity_id);
                    $.ajax({
                        'method':'post',
                        'url':'add_identity.php',
                        'data':{uname:uname}

                    }).done(function(res){
                        alert(res);
                    });
              },
          onFinish : function(authenticated, liveness){
              alert("test success");
             }
    })
})
```